# What are collating symbols and equivalence classes used for?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, locale

From grep's manual, about extended regular expressions it uses

```
‘[.’ represents the open collating symbol.
‘.]’ represents the close collating symbol.
‘[=’ represents the open equivalence class.
‘=]’ represents the close equivalence class.
```

What are collating symbols and equivalence classes used for?

How are they used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Collating symbols and equivalence classes are used in locale definitions to encode complex ordering information. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_02_04) has the details, but in summary:

- a collating symbol represents a set of characters which are considered as a single unit for collating (sorting) purposes; for example, "ch"/"Ch" or "ss" (these are only valid in locales which define them);
- an equivalence class groups characters which are equivalent for collating purposes; for example, "a" and "à" (and other accented variants).

These can be used in [RE bracket expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) by enclosing them with `[.`/`.]` and `[=`/`=]` respectively. Continuing with the examples given above, `[.ch.]` is the "ch" collating symbol, and `[=a=]` stands for the corresponding equivalence class (so in appropriate locales it is equivalent to `[aªáàâãäå...]`).